# Android Activities and Services Relationship

Tags: android, .net, multithreading, sqlite, mono

I was wondering what the relationship is between an Android service and the activity that started it (which is happening in this case, via the StartService() method) ?

Is the service just another thread running within the same process the activity belongs, or does it get its own ?

The reason I ask is b/c I'm using a SQLite DB that is going to be accessed from both an activity and the service that it kicks off, and so need to determine the proper way to syncronize DB access between them (leverage the built-in multi-threading support of SQLite, or implement some homegrown interprocess snycronization methodology).

note: I'm not asking how to syncronize access, I'm trying to figure out weather I'm accessing the DB from two seperate processes or seperate threads, which will dictate how I go about this.

note: I'm writing in .net/mono using Mono.Data.Sqlite, not in raw Android/Java.

Any insight is welcome and appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: A must read article for implementing android services: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: For anyone who decides to run their service in a seperate process, you should see http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Creating-service-in-a-new-process-td5710256.html and comment #4 at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=763

Comment: The issue with MonoDroid services that the above comment addresses has been resolved in the 4.2.4 patch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the [android developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) site not contain your answer? It goes into great detail of the `Service` and `Activity`.

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the
>   service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate
>   process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your
>   service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations
>   (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread
>   within the service to do that work. By using a separate thread, you
>   will reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors and
>   the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction
>   with your activities.

Comment: I was totally thinking about copying that caution note here too, its totally spot on. Thanks for the tip about accepting.